# Solving $I = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(x+1)\sin(2x)}{x^2 + 2x + 2}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, improper-integrals

I'm currently just starting integration of complex improper integrals, and I'm already struggling on the following integral:

$$I = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(x+1)\sin(2x)}{x^2 + 2x + 2}dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$$

So far I've thought about finding residues to apply Cauchy Residues Theorem after defining $I$ as $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}\int\limits_{-R}^R f(x)dx$. However I'm not very comfortable with this integral, and I'm not sure my method can be applied.. could anyone tell me if that's a right way to start, or  give me a clue if not?

That would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrals of this type are treated using [Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma): $$I=\Im\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z)\,dz=\Im\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R}f(z)\,dz,\quad f(z)=\frac{(z+1)e^{2iz}}{z^2+2z+2},$$ where $C_R$ is the boundary of $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<R,\Im z>0\}$, and the residue theorem: $$I=\Im\left(2\pi i\operatorname*{Res}\limits_{z=i-1}f(z)\right)=\pi e^{-2}\cos 2.$$

Comment: I think you've mixed up the real & imaginary parts. [It should be](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%2B1%29*sin%282x%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B2x%2B2%29+from+-inf+to+inf&dataset=) $\pi e^{-2}\color{blue}{\cos}2$.

Comment: @J.G.: Indeed. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed I've just seen Jordan lemma so I didn't think of it but it is a great idea to ! Thanks @metamorphy

Comment: I've tried your method @metamorphy, and also the method of Mostafa Ayaz in the answer below, but in any case the answer I find is different from yours. Indeed with your method I find $\pi i(e^{-2i-2})cos(2)$ because I find that the residue of $f$ at $-1+i$ is $\frac{e^{-2i-2}}{2}$; and with Mostafa's method I find a closer answer to yours but still not exactly the same because of the missing $i$: $\pi ie^{-2}cos(2)$ So could you either elaborate on your final result, or tell me what is wrong in mine ?

Comment: @Rhaena: Your evaluation of the residue is correct, but you have to multiply it by $2\pi i$, and *take the imaginary part* **afterwards**. [I.e., we're computing $\Im(\pi i e^{-2-2i})$.]

Comment: Ohh of course ! Not used to this lemma haha ^^ I now find exactly your answer with both methods, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Write the integral as following
$$
I{=\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\frac{(x+1)\sin(2x+2-2)}{(x+1)^2+1}dx
\\
=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\frac{u\sin(2u-2)}{u^2+1}du
\\
=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\frac{u(\sin(2u)\cos2+\cos(2u)\sin2)}{u^2+1}du
}
$$
and proceed the rest of the process through complex integration.

Comment: That seems like a nice trick ! I guess by "proceed with complex integral" you just mean to integrate this considering $u$ as a variable of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: That is right and you will end up with two complex integrals.

Comment: However after some reflexion I'm not sure how to compute those two integrals because the first one has $u\sin(2u)$ as a numerator and the second $u\cos(2u)$; I first thought it was a Fourier transform but it can't be because of the $1$ in the denominator and the $2u$ in $\sin$ and $\cos$. So how can we proceed ? If it's not too much to ask of you

Comment: @Rhaena The cosine part is odd, so vanishes; the sine part is easy with the residue theorem, using $\sin2u=\Im\exp2iu$.

Comment: Okey I think I see for the sine part, but why does to cosine part vanish entirely if it is odd ?

Comment: It is actually that $\frac{u\cos 2u}{u^2+1}$ is an odd function and its integral over a symmetric interval like $\mathbb R$ is zero.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that thanks for explaining!